# Nornalize nested dict to a single dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an actual structure I am reading from a file :

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Explosives",
  "category_id": 1,
  "average_price": 294,
  "is_rare": 0,
  "max_buy_price": 755,
  "max_sell_price": 1774,
  "min_buy_price": 99,
  "min_sell_price": 18,
  "buy_price_lower_average": 176,
  "sell_price_upper_average": 924,
  "is_non_marketable": 0,
  "ed_id": 128049204,
  ** "category": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Chemicals"
  } **
}
```

I am trying to create one single list to insert in a database after. The data in the dictionary at the end should be also at the end of my list.

As you can see below, I have dict inside my dict at the end. My actual code - which is working - is :

```
 for v in d:
        commodities_reference = []
        for k, g in v.items():
            if isinstance(g, dict):
                dict1 = g
                my_value1 = dict1.get("id")
                my_value2 = dict1.get("name")

        for s, i in v.items():
            if not isinstance(i, dict):
                commodities_reference.append(i)
        commodities_reference.append(my_value1)
        commodities_reference.append(my_value2)
```

Nevertheless, I would like to know if there is a more "pythonic" way to do it since it looks a bit ugly to me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question is probably a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/  because your code works, but you just want advice on making it nicer.

Comment: Perhaps you could add a remark about what you are trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: Instead of iterating over `v.items()` twice, you could add an `elif:` block

Comment: I am trying to create one single list to insert in a database after. The data in the dictionnary at the end should be also at the end of my list. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: I will follow your advice @Jean-FrançoisCorbett and post there.

Answer (score 0):

```
v = {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Explosives",
    "category_id": 1,
    "average_price": 294,
    "is_rare": 0,
    "max_buy_price": 755,
    "max_sell_price": 1774,
    "min_buy_price": 99,
    "min_sell_price": 18,
    "buy_price_lower_average": 176,
    "sell_price_upper_average": 924,
    "is_non_marketable": 0,
    "ed_id": 128049204,
    "category": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Chemicals"
    }
}

commodities_reference = []

for val in v.values():
    if isinstance(val, dict):
        commodities_reference.extend(val.values())
    else:
        commodities_reference.append(val)

print(commodities_reference)
```

Or if you want to be really concise but less readable:

```
for val in v.values():
    commodities_reference += val.values() if isinstance(val, dict) else [val]
```

Comment: It doesn't fit what I want. Output is a list of all values from the different dics with the actual data from nested dict at the end of the list.